# Assetic dump not found

Tags: symfony

I have a folder `css` in a web folder. When I run `php app/console assetic:dump` it returns:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
>   There are no commands defined in the "assetic" namespace.
>   Did you mean this?
>   assets

I have no idea what happend.

Comment: Thx. I have already installed, but when I put the same command it return me again [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
There are no commands defined in the "assetic" namespace.
Did you mean this?
assets